# Automatically create and update tables in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, package

I have a prototype server connected to a PostgreSQL database. Because I'm iterating rapidly, I'm creating tables and changing the schemas all the time. I've looked for an npm package which allows me to create such tables and update existing schemas once the server starts, but the options I've found are tied to an ORM implementation, which I do not need.

TL;DR: Are there any npm packages to automatically create tables and update schemas according to a single configuration object provided to it?

Comment: what ORM implementation have you found and highlight the feature? Just to understand the requirement correctly.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can name SequelizeJS http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but [node-pg-migrate](https://salsita.github.io/node-pg-migrate/#/) should do what you need.